# Synchronous Ajax: Guaranteed sequential?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I know that synchronous Ajax is deprecated. But I have some code that is using it anyway, and my question is this:

Suppose a method A makes a normal (asynchronous) Ajax request that is pending with the server. Meanwhile, some other event triggers method B which makes a synchronous Ajax request. Now, suppose the response from A comes in before the response from B. Is it possible that the `onreadystatechange` callback from A will run first? Or does `async = false` guarantee that the synchronous method (B) will be the very next piece of Javascript code to run no matter what?

I'm using jQuery's Ajax methods if that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible that the onreadystatechange callback from A will run first?

No. The event loop is stuck waiting for the synchronous request to finish. All other events will be queued up until the JS stops being busy waiting.

Comment: What if A isn't another Ajax request but an asynchronously-loaded `script` tag that finally completes?

Comment: The JS event loop is still too busy to run another function.